# PostgreSQL 12 and PostGIS 3.0.1: ERROR: could not access file "$libdir/postgis-3": No such file or directory on Linux

Tags: postgresql, postgis, postgresql-12

I have `Linux Mint 19.2` where I installed the newest PostgreSQL 12 using:

`sudo apt-get install postgresql`

Similarly, I installed the newest Postgis 3.0.1 using:

`sudo apt-get install postgis`

I setup postgres account and everything and wanted to create an extension of PostGIS. I thus had to install also `postgresql-12-postgis-3-scripts`, which added postgis.control into PostgreSQL installation.

I then connected to my `postgres` account, created and initialised a `test` database and attempted to `create extension postgis`. The answer was:

`ERROR:  could not access file "$libdir/postgis-3": No such file or directory`

Both PostgreSQL and PostGIS were fresh installs. I have no broken dependencies or old PostgreSQL fragments on my computer...
What am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You were close. Try installing `postgis` in your PostgreSQL 12 like this:

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-12-postgis-3
```

After that you'll be able to successfully run

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

Comment: Oh yes, spot on! I didn't know postgresql-12-postgis-3 existed. Thought the bundle would be created automatically on PostGIS install. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

On Arch Linux you need to install [`postgis-old-upgrade`](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/postgis-old-upgrade/) alongside `postgresql-old-upgrade`.

Answer (score 2):

- I tried the answer by @JimJones and it worked for me previously but when i got this error again i kept getting
  `Package postgresql-12-postgis-3 is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source  E: Package 'postgresql-12-postgis-3' has no installation candidate` on trying same solution again.
- What worked for me was installing gnupg2.

  - Steps

    ```
    sudo apt -y install gnupg2

    wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -

    echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ `lsb_release -cs`-pgdg 
    main" |sudo tee  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list

    sudo apt update

    sudo apt install postgis postgresql-12-postgis-3
    ```
  - source -> https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-postgis-on-ubuntu-debian/